# fetch different columns from two tables and combine the results

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to combine the Two different tables result in oracle.
conditions:

1. From both the tables ID ,STAMp columns are common columns.
2. Remaining columns are different.

Table1;

```
Element_ID  STAMP           Col1     Col2 
1           22/03/2014     85         100

2           22/03/2014     95         105
```

Table2.

```
Element_ID   STAMP        Col3      Col4

5            22/03/2014     100      110
6            22/04/2014     200      210
```

**Result:**

```
Element_ID  STAMP        Col1    Col3

1           22/03/2014   85       null
5           22/03/2014   null     100
```

Query:

```
Select Element_ID, Stamp, Col1 from Table1 where element_ID in (1, 5)

Select Element_ID, STAMP, Col3 from Table2 where Element_ID in (1,5)
```

How to combine the above two queries results, and results should come as above format.

Comment: Please some moderator format the code part. I think in Result there are 2 Rows shown in single row.

Comment: Why `Col1` is null in the result set for `22/03/2014` whereas it has a matching part (in fact _two_) in `Table1` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as this,

```
Select Element_ID, Stamp, Col1, NULL Col3 from Table1 where element_ID in (1,5)
union
Select Element_ID, STAMP, NULL Col1, Col3 from Table2 where Element_ID in (1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select T1.Element_ID,T1.Stamp, T1.Col1, T2.Col3 
   from Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
      where T1.Element_ID in (1, 5)
```

Comment: This would not fetch any results as there is no element_id = 5 in T1. Also the join on T1.Element_ID = T2.Element_ID is not useful because of the same reason. You shud think of maybe adding an outer join.

Comment: I wrote that considering error in RESULT. For what i perceived, it is like
`Element_ID STAMP Col1 Col3`
`1 22/03/2014 85 null`
`5 22/03/2014 null 100` TWO DIFFERENT ROWS

Comment: Ya, agreed, the check for T1.Element_ID = T2.Element_ID is of no worth here. i mistook it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one interesting use case for a `RIGHT JOIN` on some minimum set -- both to restrict the result to records 1 and 5 *and* to force the presence of those two records:

```
SELECT "Element_ID", "STAMP", "Col1", "Col3"
FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2
USING("Element_ID", "STAMP")
RIGHT JOIN
(
  SELECT 1 "Element_ID" FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 FROM DUAL
) MinimumSet
USING("Element_ID")
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/725d9/18 for a live example